# How to style div to make it look like my attached image

Tags: html, css

Please help me style my div to make it like my attached image. I've tried but can't figure out

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.home {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20rem;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.home:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2rem;
  left: 40%;
  border-top: 17px solid black;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">Blogs</div>
```

Comment: You can do it adding a ``span`` tag if it's hard for you to use pseudo.